# Fit simulation to data with multiple fitting parameters

Tags: matlab

I have a set of experimental points

```
Xdata=[xd1 xd2...]

Ydata=[yd1 yd2...]
```

And a `function y=myfunction(xsimul,a,b,c)` that indirectly simulates:

```
Ysimul=[ys1 ys2...]
```

for a `Xsimul=Xdata`

By indirectly I mean there is no direct calculation y=Function(x,a,b,c). It is instead obtained within two for loops by minimization of another function g=f(z)(using fminsearch) followed by Ysimul=(g(targetvalue)).

The goal is to fit the simulation to the experimental data and retrieve optimum a, b and c values by a least-squares method. 
I can give a good initial guess to the parameters. However having 3 fitting parameters, along with the already big computing time for determining Ysimul makes this problem quite cumbersome. 
So what I would like to know is:

Is this problem feasible using functions like lsqcurvefit?
If so, can you provide hints on how to do it?

Comment: To confirm here: 'Xdata' and 'Ydata' are equal sized vectors?  'a', 'b', and 'c' are scalars? And the goal is to find the best estimate of 'a', 'b', and 'c' to fit the provided data?

Comment: Yes Xdata and Ydata are equal sized and a,b,c are scalars to be estimated. I should have pointed that out. And thank you for the quick reply! I will try to implement the algorithm based on your hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just the solution**

This is a pretty standard use of `lsqnonlin`, you just need to get it formatted correctly. That means something like this:

```
%First, define a function whose inputs are a single vector, and whose
%outputs can be minimized
funToMinimize = @(abc) myfunction(Xdata,abc(1), abc(2), abc(3)) - Ydata;

%Define an initial guess of the values (including the size of the vector)
abcInitial = [0 0 0]; %Or whatever your best guess is

%Then use the nonlinear fit
abcFit = lsqnonlin(funToMinimize , abcInitial);
```

---

**Demonstration**

I obviously can't generate a solution to your `myfunction` problem, but we can still walk through the important steps.

First, let's define a function to simulate your `myfunction`, `Xdata`, and `Ydata`.

```
%Define some complicated-ish "myfuction", with inputs that match yours
myfunction = @(xsimul, a, b, c) sqrt(abs(xsimul))*a + sin(xsimul)*b*a^2 + c;
%Define "Xdata"
Xdata = linspace(0,10,100);
%Define "Ydata", note that I'm sneaking in a set of (a, b, c) values here
Ydata = myfunction(Xdata, 1, 2, 3);
```

Now, let's run the steps in the answer above:

```
funToMinimize = @(abc) myfunction(Xdata,abc(1), abc(2), abc(3)) - Ydata;
abcInitial = [0 0 0];
abcFit = lsqnonlin(funToMinimize , abcInitial)
```

The last step should return `[1 2 3]`, matching the (a, b, c) values used to generate `Ydata`.